# Parameters for DbGeometry.FromGml()

Tags: .net, spatial

I'm trying to use `System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry.FromGml()` from the System.Data.Entity assembly, but I can't get a simple test case to work.

```
[Test]
public void DbGeometry_FromGml()
{
    StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();

    xml.Append(@"<gml:PolygonPatch>");

    xml.Append(@"<gml:exterior>");
    xml.Append(@"<gml:Ring>");
    xml.Append(@"<gml:curveMember>");
    xml.Append(@"<gml:segments>");
    xml.Append(@"<gml:GeodesicString>");
    xml.Append(@"<gml:posList> -25.07842078 124.85121167 -24.07829967 114.86532597 </gml:posList>");
    xml.Append(@"</gml:GeodesicString>");
    xml.Append(@"</gml:segments>");
    xml.Append(@"</gml:curveMember>");
    xml.Append(@"</gml:Ring>");
    xml.Append(@"</gml:exterior>");
    xml.Append(@"</gml:PolygonPatch>");

    DbGeometry g = DbGeometry.FromGml(xml.ToString());
}
```

This gives me an exception that 'gml' is an undeclared prefix. I add some XML namespaces to the PolygonPatch: `xmlns:gml=\"http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2\"` and then I get a different error (same error occurs if I remove the `gml:` prefix instead of defining it):

```
Test.UnitTests.DbGeometry_FromGml:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.FormatException : 24129: The given XML instance is not valid because the top-level tag is PolygonPatch. The top-level element of the input Geographic Markup Language (GML) must contain a Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiGeometry, MultiCurve, MultiSurface, Arc, ArcString, CompositeCurve, PolygonPatch or FullGlobe (geography Data Type only) object.
```

Since it says the top-level element must `contain` a PolygonPatch I tried wrapping it in a parent node (and moving the namespace stuff up to the parent), but it made no difference.

So I'm confused: What does the GML fed to this method need to look like?

**Update**
Tried a simpler object (Point) and had similar problems. I created a DbGeometry from text and then dumped it's GML and it was different to my input, so I think it might be related to GML versions.

```
DbGeometry point = DbGeometry.FromText("POINT (0 0)");
string gml = point.AsGml();
System.Console.WriteLine(gml);
```

Output

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><pos>0 0</pos></Point>`

So a Point contains a `<pos>` rather than `<coordinates>`